# Having problems getting velodyne_simulator to make

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the velodyne_simulator package to get a VLP-16 working in conjunction with a model of an ev. I cloned the repository a couple of weeks ago and have been working off that which has been working incredibly well.

Yesterday I was trying to make sure I could recreate my workspace so that others could have access to it and was writing a set of instructions for setup which included cloning the repository. When I tried to call catkin_make on my new test workspace I got an error message

> CMake Error at
> /home/hugh/Desktop/alpha/devel/share/gazebo_plugins/cmake/gazebo_pluginsConfig.cmake:141
> (message):   Project
> 'velodyne_gazebo_plugins' tried to
> find library '-lpthread'.  The
> library is neither a target nor
> built/installed properly.  Did you
> compile   project 'gazebo_plugins'?
> Did you find_package() it before the
> subdirectory   containing its code is
> included? Call Stack (most recent call
> first):
> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76
> (find_package)
> velodyne_simulator/velodyne_gazebo_plugins/CMakeLists.txt:4
> (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
> "/home/hugh/Desktop/alpha/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also
> "/home/hugh/Desktop/alpha/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> Makefile:7416: recipe for target
> 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
> make: *** [cmake_check_build_system]
> Error 1 Invoking "make
> cmake_check_build_system" failed <

I was wondering if anybody had encountered this problem before and know a solution or can think of something that I have missed which has caused this?  I am quite new to ROS and gazebo so I wouldn’t be surprised if I have missed something blindingly obvious.

When I copy over all of the folders in the src directory from my currently working workspace to the new one, catkin_make works properly but when I move just the velodyne_description folder over it still doesn’t work.

Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254458/having-problems-getting-velodyne_simulator-to-make/) by [H_Gottlieb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29061/h_gottlieb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be an issue affecting several gazebo plugin ROS packages:
http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=gazebo
http://build.ros.org/view/Kbin_uX64/job/Kbin_uX64__hector_gazebo_thermal_camera__ubuntu_xenial_amd64__binary/
http://build.ros.org/view/Kbin_uX64/job/Kbin_uX64__kobuki_gazebo_plugins__ubuntu_xenial_amd64__binary/
http://build.ros.org/view/Kbin_uX64/job/Kbin_uX64__velodyne_gazebo_plugins__ubuntu_xenial_amd64__binary/

There is some discussion here:
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/537/files
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2198/gazebo7-linking-error-with-cmake-catkin

However, this should only be an issue if you compile `gazebo_ros_pkgs` from source. It shouldn't be a problem if you install with `apt-get`:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2017-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [H_Gottlieb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29061/h_gottlieb/) on 2017-02-25**:
Hey!

Sorry I didn't update this post. Still not really sure why there was the problem but my man, kmhallen, is completely right. If you use sudo apt-get to install the binaries then the problem was fixed.